# google map display different location

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have one address and when i see in google map it display correct but when i put in my php page innside div it display different name can you please help me to solve this.

```
            fillAddress(i,srmode,phmid);
            var addr = $("#curPhmName").html()+", "+$("#mapadd"+i).html();
            console.log(addr+"-jignesh");
            var mapProp = {
              center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
              zoom:12,
              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("regGoogleMap"),mapProp);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
             url: "http://www.google.com/maps/search/"+addr,
            });

            var contentString=$("#marker_address").html();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            marker.setMap(map);
```

[image]

Comment: From where did youget the `latitude,longitude`

Comment: We have table and put lat long inside. but we have check same lat long in google map it display same issue.

Comment: *it display same issue* means is it a different location?

Comment: diffrent name display on map but same lat lng

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `placeId` and the places library to get that data:

```
  service.getDetails({
    placeId: "ChIJ5_fxvXQtdEgRJ_xKnVYHZeg"
  }, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(21);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
          'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
          place.formatted_address + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
    }
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yu6x3tzs/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196},
    zoom: 15
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
    placeId: "ChIJ5_fxvXQtdEgRJ_xKnVYHZeg"
  }, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(21);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
          'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
          place.formatted_address + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it is display day lewis pharmacy but when you see the google map it display another location name. i dont want daylewis pharmacy. i want just pined address which is on map. but when we put locator in address it will display avissinca pharmacy image on map. please check